# Append to logfile using Azure function output binding

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have a simple function that is triggered by an upload to a blob container. It then writes a file with some simple info on the file uploaded to another container (new txt file for each file uploaded).

I also want to write the info to a single log file in another container (logs).

The log file is always truncated after each upload, rather than the info appended to the file.

Writing a log file using an output binding must be possible but has be stumped as the binding is write only. StreamWriter seems to have the ability to append but only when the constructor is passed a file rather than a stream.

Can you point me in the right direction ?

```
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

public static void Run(Stream myBlob, string name, string extension, Stream outputBlob, Stream logBlob, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed text file blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
 
    string details = "A file has been uploaded called : " + name + "." + extension;
    string logitem= "The following file was uploaded: " + name;

    //create a txt file with some info in about the input file 
    outputBlob.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(details),0,details.Length); 

    //log some information to a file by passing the output binding logBlob stream to the streamwriter 
    using (StreamWriter s = new StreamWriter(logBlob))
    {
            s.Write(logitem);
    }
     
}
```

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myBlob",
      "path": "images/{name}.{extension}",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "direction": "in",
      "type": "blobTrigger"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputBlob",
      "direction": "out",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "files/{name}-copy.txt",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    },
    {
      "name": "logBlob",
      "path": "logs/uploadlog.txt",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "direction": "out",
      "type": "blob"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the workarounds is that we try to save all the logs to our SQL database.

**PREREQUISITES:**

1. SQL Database resource.
2. Table in your Database.
3. Connection string of your SQL Database.

Here is the code that you can try

```cs
// Define the details that you want to add
var details = "A file has been uploaded called : " + name + "." + extension;
var logitem= "The following file was uploaded: " + name;

// Prepare the SQL Query
var query = $ "INSERT INTO [ApplicationLogs] ([details],[logitem]) VALUES('{details}', '{logitem}')";

// Prepare the SQL command and execute query
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
```

For more information, you can refer [Send logs from Azure Functions to Azure SQL Database](https://www.sqlshack.com/logging-messages-from-azure-functions-to-azure-sql-database/)